# If $\{x\}=\{z\}$ then $x=z$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think that no. For example, Let $x=\{1,2,3\}$ and $z=\{1,2,3,4\}$. So, $\{\{1,2,3\}\}=\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$. Yet, $x\neq z$.

Can you explain?

Comment: Your example is incorrect. It is not true that $\{\{1,2,3\}\}=\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$.

Comment: @SteveKass Why not?

Comment: @Kahler: Because the only element of the set $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ is the set $\{1,2,3\}$, the only element of the set $\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$ is the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$, and these elements $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4\}$ are not equal.

Comment: Why on earth do you think {{1,2,3}} = {{1,2,3,4}}?????? It obviously does not.

Comment: If $x \ne y $ then {$y$} $\ne $ {$y$}.  So contrapositively the statement is true.

Comment: Why not?!?! Because the two sets have completely different elements. {1,2,3} $\in $ {{1,2,3}}. But {1,2,3} $\not \in $ {{1,2,3,4}}. They can't be equal if one has one element and the other has another!

Answer (score 8):

By definition two sets are equal if and only if they have the same members: $x=y$ if and only if $\forall z(z\in x\leftrightarrow z\in y)$. In your example the sets $\{x\}$ and $\{z\}$ are assumed to be equal, so they must have exactly the same elements. The only element of $\{x\}$ is $x$, and the only element of $\{z\}$ is $z$, so it must be the case that $x=z$.

As was noted in the comments, your example is incorrect: if $x=\{1,2,3\}$ and $z=\{1,2,3,4\}$, then $x\ne z$, so $\{x\}\ne\{z\}$.

Comment: @Kahler: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

> Notice that in order to prove that two set $A$ and $B$ are equal, we need to show: $$A\subseteq B~~~~ \text{and}~~~~ B\subseteq A$$

In this case we have the set $x=\{1,2,3\}$ and $z=\{1,2,3,4\}$.

We can clearly see that $x \subset z$, since every element of $x$ is contained in $z$. In order to show equality, we now also need $z\subset x$.

However, since $4 \in z$, but $4 \not\in x$ we have that $z \not\subset x$.

So $x \neq z$.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to hazard a guess that when the OP says

> Let x={1,2,3} and z={1,2,3,4}. So, {{1,2,3}}={{1,2,3,4}}

that he or she is confusing "equal sets" with "equal size sets".  It is definitely **true** that $\{ \{1,2,3 \}\} $ and $\{ \{1,2,3,4\}\}$ are both sets containing a single element, and they are therefore **equal in size**.  But they are not **equal sets**.  "Equal sets" means "the same sets", which means "sets containing the same elements".  If you want to indicate that the two sets are the same size, use the notation $ \left| \{ \{1,2,3 \} \} \right| = \left| \{ \{ 1,2,3,4 \} \} \right|$.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. x $\neq z$.
$$x=\{1,2,3\}\  and\ z=\{1,2,3,4\}\ then\ x \neq z.
$$

But because all of $x$ is in $z$ and $z$ has items $x$ does not have, $x$ $\subseteq$ $z$. Meaning x is a proper subset of $z$.

Answer (score 0):

By extensionality of sets, there is an equivalence

$$\{ x \} = \{ z \} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \forall t: (t \in \{ x \} \Leftrightarrow t \in \{ z \}) $$

By definition of set enumeration notation, there is an equivalence

$$ a \in \{ b \} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad a = b $$

Substituting this into the above equivalence,

$$\{ x \} = \{ z \} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \forall t: (t = x  \Leftrightarrow t =z) $$

The right hand side is equivalent to $x=z$. But if you need to see that proved, I will instead prove something simpler: by substituting $t = x$, we get

$$ \forall t: (t = x  \Leftrightarrow t =z) \implies (x=x \Leftrightarrow x=z) \implies x=z $$

and consequently,

$$\{ x \} = \{ z \} \quad \implies \quad x=z $$

The other direction

$$ \{ x \} = \{ z \} \quad \Longleftarrow \quad x=z $$

is proven by substitution, thus

$$ \{ x \} = \{ z \} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad x=z $$

---

Your error is that $\{\{1,2,3\}\} \neq \{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$.

Answer (score -1):

$x$ consists of $4$ elements, $z$ consists of $3$ elements. Obviously, they **cannot** be equal.

Comment: The op *doesnt* think x =z.  Yet somehow the op believes {x} = {z} which are two sets with single elements.  Yet as the elements are different I haven't got the slightest idea why the op believes these set are equal.